# Need to extract only the names from an array of hashes using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an output as follows:

```
[#<table1 employeename: "abc">, #<table1 employeename: "bbb">, #<table1 employeename: "ccc">, #<table1 employeename: "ddd">, #<table1 employeename: "eee">]
```

I would like to retrieve only the employee names in the following format using Ruby, please help as I am very new to Ruby?

```
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee')
```

Comment: Try this `[#, #, #, #, #].map(&:name)`, where name is a attribute of your employee object.

Comment: hey thank you.. that indeed worked  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are riding the Rails, you can use the [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) method to accomplish this

```
Employee.pluck(:name)
#=> ["Ashley", "John", "Peter", "Julie"]
```

which is equivalent to

```
Employee.all.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one you can queried data with selected attributes like

```
@data = Data.all.select("name")
```